# time.sleep skips multiple lines in my script

Tags: python, tkinter, time

```
def fctCountdown():
    t = 3
    countdown = Label(Pong, text = "3", font = ("Fixedsys", 30), bg = "#CB997E", fg = 'black')
    countdown.place(x = 387, y = 300)
    while t >= 0: 
        if t == 2:
            countdown.config(text = "2")
        if t == 1:
            countdown.config(text = "1")
        if t == 0:
            countdown.config(text = "Start !")
        sleep(1) 
        t -= 1
    countdown.place_forget()

def fctGoDown():
    global x1, y1
    
def fctGameMenu():
    background_image = PhotoImage(master = Pong, file = "fondpong0.png")
    background_label = Label(Pong, image = background_image)
    background_label.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    background_label.image = background_image

def fctStartGame(evt):
    global state
    if state == 0:
        state = 1
        fctGameMenu()
        sleep(1)
        fctCountdown()
```

Hi guys ! I'm asking you for help because the sleep(1) line in fctStartGame is executed before the fctGameMenu() and i don't understand why. Because of it my countdown doesn't work.

Comment: It's not skipping lines, the lines are simply not having any visible effect because you never gave the GUI any chance to update.  During `time.sleep()`, your program is doing *absolutely nothing*.  The proper way to add delays to a Tkinter program is to use the `.after()` method to schedule the next action for some point in the future.  While waiting for that point to arrive, the GUI is still fully responsive.

Comment: Thank you very much !! I didn't know about after(), i'm gonna try that